# std::unordered_set with custom allocator

Tags: c++, stl

Good evening,

RESOLUTION: The issue was coming from the explicit keyword from my allocator ctors.

EDIT: I've been finally able to locate the issue. It's seems to come from the move ctor of unordered_set when it's used with some custom allocator. Still digging.

EDIT: Weird thing is that there is no issue when using my custom allocator and a std::vector.

Why do I get an error message when I try to copy an element from :

```
typedef std::unordered_set< const CScopeProfiler* > CInternalScopeProfilersSet;
```

to :

```
typedef std::unordered_set< const CScopeProfiler*, std::hash< const CScopeProfiler* >, std::equal_to< const CScopeProfiler* >, CAllocator< const CScopeProfiler* > > CScopeProfilersSet;
```

as follows :

```
CProfiler::CScopeProfilersSet CProfiler::ScopeProfilersRegistry() const
{
    CScopeProfilersSet kSet;

    kSet.insert( *( m_pkRegister->begin() ) );

    return kSet;
}
```

The exact error message is given in french, so the approximate translation would be :

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'std::_Hash<_Traits>::_Hash(const std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq> &,const GameForge::Core::CAllocator<T> &)' : impossible to convert second parameter of 'std::_Wrap_alloc<_Alloc>' to 'const GameForge::Core::CAllocator<T> &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\unordered_set    195 1
```

Note that if I don't put the kSet.insert(), I don't get the error.

The typedefs are done in the scope of CProfiler.

I've been stuck for days now, and it doesn't seem to come from the hasher as one could expect. Any idea is welcome, and sorry if the post isn't properly formed as it's my first post on StackOverflow.

PS : As requested here is the code snippet.

```
namespace GameForge
{
    namespace Core
    {
        class CAllocationsHistogram;

        // Ensure profiling code isn't profiled.
        class GF_API CProfiler
        {
        public:
            class CScopeRun;

            class GF_API CScopeProfiler
            {
                friend CProfiler;
                friend CScopeRun;

            public:
                CScopeProfiler( const char* pcLabel );
                ~CScopeProfiler();
            };

            class GF_API CScopeRun
            {
                friend CProfiler;

            public:
                CScopeRun( CScopeProfiler& rkScopeProfiler );
                ~CScopeRun();
            };

            typedef std::unordered_set< const CScopeProfiler*,
                                        std::hash< const CScopeProfiler* >,
                                        std::equal_to< const CScopeProfiler* >,
                                        CAllocator< const CScopeProfiler* > > CScopeProfilersSet;

        private:
            typedef std::unordered_set< const CScopeProfiler* > CInternalScopeProfilersSet;

        public:
            CScopeProfilersSet ScopeProfilersRegistry() const;

        protected:
            CProfiler();
            ~CProfiler();

        private:
            CInternalScopeProfilersSet* m_pkRegister;
        };
```

Comment: I don’t believe that, please post a minimal, complete code snippet exhibiting this behaviour.

Comment: … the emphasis was really on **minimal** code.

Comment: Well as i don't really understand the matter it's quite hard to post the minimal code.

Comment: That’s an important part of debugging: reducing the code stepwise until it no longer produces the error.

Comment: That's the minimum in my opinion.

Comment: It’s not really minimal. For instance you can remove constructor and destructor declarations, the `friend` declarations and the namespaces. It is also not **complete**. As in, I cannot compile or execute it. As a consequence it’s really quite useless for finding the error. Here is the minimised (but of course still not complete) code – you might notice that it’s less than half the length of yours: https://gist.github.com/klmr/5485096

Comment: See my edited answer - yes, the insert() was a red herring.  Real problem is with CAllocator...

Answer (score 0):

Because, unfortunately, your two containers are different types.  And so, consequently are their iterators.  This problem is what SCARY iterators are designed to resolve - when containers should be considered equivalent for iteration purposes, even though their types are distinct.  The workaround is either to unify your container types (maybe deriving one from another), or rewrite not to depend on iterator-based algorithms (dereference and copy elements individually).

**EDIT:**
I was able to repro with a simple example, which has nothing to do with the insert() call, but rather the rvalue move ctor of the temporary kSet.  With C++11, there are a few new requirements for your custom allocator - particularly the rebind type function.  See [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764229/stl-bug-cant-copy-basic-string-with-custom-allocator) for more info.

```
template<typename T>
struct CAllocator : allocator<T>
{
    CAllocator(){}

    template <class U>
    CAllocator(CAllocator<U> const &) {}

    // This required to ensure custom allocator is propagated in move semantics
    template <class U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef CAllocator<U> other;
    };
};

typedef std::unordered_set< const CScopeProfiler*, std::hash< const CScopeProfiler* >, std::equal_to< const CScopeProfiler* >, CAllocator< const CScopeProfiler * > >  CScopeProfilersSet;

CScopeProfilersSet ScopeProfilersRegistry()
{
    CScopeProfilersSet kSet;
    return kSet;
};
```

Comment: The code isn’t actually passing iterators around – it’s passing (references to) *values*.

Comment: It's true - with incomplete code, I was assuming the dereference may have been a mistake, and was going on the compiler error msg, which indicates a direct mismatch between allocator types (one the STL default, and the other custom), indicating a container type mismatch.

Comment: @Adrian - what happens if you separate things out:
  auto& elem = *( m_pkRegister->begin() );
  kSet.insert( elem );

Comment: My allocator actually define the rebind struct as follow,

`template< typename U >
 struct rebind
 { 
                                typedef CAllocator< U > other;
                        };
`

I can't test right now, but my allocator doesn't inherit from std::allocator as i understood that any class could be an allocator if it could meet the interface requierements.

Comment: I found that the two ctors in CAllocator were also necessary - I didn't dive into the VC++11 implementation any further (allocator_traits, etc).  I suggest you merge my skeleton with your implementation, maybe in stages.

Comment: I've used your skeleton and still have the error. The only change was to inherit from `std::allocator< T >`. Btw thank you for the time you're spending on my problem ;).